# funcion para validar ip con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ip

Buen día amigos del foro

Recurro nuevamente a ustedes en busca de ayuda, esta vez para realizar una función que valide direcciones ip dentro de un campo tipo textarea.

Yo tengo esta función javascript :

```
function validateIp(idForm) 
{ 

    object=document.getElementById(idForm); 
    valueForm=object.value; 


    var patronIp=new RegExp("^([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})$"); 

    if(valueForm.search(patronIp)==0) 
    { 

        valores=valueForm.split("."); 
        if(valores[0]<=255 && valores[1]<=255 && valores[2]<=255 && valores[3]<=255) 
        { 

            object.style.color="#000"; 
            return; 
        } 
    } 

    object.style.color="#f00"; 
}
```

Ella valida la primera direccion ip que se escribe de manera perfecta, pero como es un textarea no valida las demas que se escriben, la idea es que valide cada una de ellas separadas por un salto de linea y cuando se precione el boton enviar el valide si todas son correctas o si alguna esta incorrecta devuelva un alert y no deje enviar el formulario.

En el textarea se van a escribir una debajo de la otra, pero cuando se escribe una segunda direccion ip falla.

Si me pueden ayudar con alguna otra funcion o corregirme la funcion.

Muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda y su valioso tiempo amigos mios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada separaría un poco la función, para que no una haga todo el trabajo. Esto hace que sea más fácil testear y más fácil encontrar errores a futuro:

```
// llamaría validateIp a una función que valide directamente la ip que se pasa
function validateIp(ip) {
  var patronIp = new RegExp("^([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})$");
  var valores;

  // early return si la ip no tiene el formato correcto.
  if(ip.search(patronIp) !== 0) {
    return false
  }

  valores = ip.split("."); 

  return valores[0] <= 255 && valores[1] <= 255 && valores[2] <= 255 && valores[3] <= 255
}

function validateForm(idForm) {
  var object = document.getElementById(idForm);
  var valueForm = object.value.split('\n'); // generamos un array de valores separado por el salto de linea
  var isValid = valueForm.every(validateIp) // validamos que todos los elementos cumplan con la condición dada en validateIp

  if (isValid) {
    object.style.color = "#000"; 
    return; 
  }

  object.style.color = "#f00";
}
```

Edit: Ejemplo funcionando [acá](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wilson-c9c88)

Comment: Hola Yakume Muchisimas gracias por responder, pero la función siempre me arroja incorrectas las ip, las marca todas en roja indiferentemente si esta correcta o no, como hago en ese caso ??

Comment: edité la respuesta en la linea que había un error (valores = ip.split("."), estaba usando valueForm).
No se puede cambiar el color de una linea sola, porque están todas las ips en el mismo textarea.

Comment: Ah ok ya entendi como funciona, muchisiimas gracias amigo